# OpenGL ES 2 How To Render to Texture and Extract Data for GPGPU Test

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl-es

I am attempting to submit a small float array as an OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture and read it back in order to understand GPGPU better. I am attempting to do this on the SGX 530 GPU on a TI OMAP3 ARM SoC.

I've been following this guide: 
[enter link description here](http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/tutorial.html#kernel1)

My code currently creates and populates 2 float arrays, and then creates "pass through" shaders like this:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{

    // Max texture size in each direction
    int maxSize;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE,&maxSize);
    texSize = sqrt(maxSize);
    texSize = 2;
    qDebug() << "GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE " << maxSize << " SQRT " << texSize;

    // Define input and output arrays of RGBA format with each channel being u8
    m_Format = 4;
    dataX = (quint8*)malloc(m_Format*texSize*texSize*sizeof(quint8));
    dataY = (quint8*)malloc(m_Format*texSize*texSize*sizeof(quint8));

    // Setup some dummy data
    int arraySize = m_Format*texSize*texSize;
    qDebug() << "Array Size: " << arraySize;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++) {
        dataX[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++) {
        dataY[i] = 0;
    }

    QGLShader *vshader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Vertex);
    const char *vsrc =
            "attribute highp vec4 vertex;\n"
            "attribute highp vec4 texCoord;\n"
            "varying vec2 texc;\n"
            "void main(void)\n"
            "{\n"
            "    gl_Position = vertex;\n"
            "    texc = texCoord.xy;\n"
            "}\n";
    vshader->compileSourceCode(vsrc);

    QGLShader *fshader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Fragment);
    const char *fsrc =
            "varying highp vec2 texc;\n"
            "uniform sampler2D tex;\n"
            "void main(void)\n"
            "{\n"
            "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, texc);\n"
            "}\n";
    fshader->compileSourceCode(fsrc);

    program.addShader(vshader);
    program.addShader(fshader);
    program.link();

    vertexAttr = program.attributeLocation("vertex");
    texCoordAttr = program.attributeLocation("texCoord");
    textureUniform = program.uniformLocation("tex");

}
```

I then attempt to submit the texture to the GPU, render it to a framebuffer, and read it back like this:

```
void GLWidget::renderToScene()
{

    // Bind and configure a texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &m_hTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_hTexture);
    glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texSize, texSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataX); // Allocate buffer to hold RGBA with 8 bytes each

    // Generate handles for Frame Buffer Object
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_hFBO);

    // Switch the render target to the current FBO to update the texture map
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_hFBO);

    qDebug() << "Data before roundtrip:";
    int arraySize = m_Format*texSize*texSize;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arraySize ; i++)
        qDebug() << dataX[i];

    // FBO attachment is complete?
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {

        qDebug() << "Frame buffer is present...";
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_hTexture, 0);
        //glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,texSize,texSize, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,dataX); // pixel data is RGBA and each channel u8

        static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,
        };

        static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,  1.0f,
            0.0f,  0.0f,
        };

        // ensure no VBOs or IBOs are bound
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Set pointers to the arrays
        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON);

    }

    qDebug() << "Zero data:";
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++)
        qDebug() << dataY[i];

    // GPGPU Extract
    glReadPixels(0, 0, texSize, texSize, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,dataY);

    // print out results
    qDebug() << "Data after roundtrip:";
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++)
        qDebug() << dataY[i];

    // Unbind the FBO so rendering will return to the main buffer.
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    qDebug() << "Done...";
    sleep(60000);

}
```

The draw call looks like this:

```
void GLWidget::draw() {

    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Draw
    program.bind();
    renderToScene();
    program.release();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    swapBuffers();

}
```

Everything compiles and runs, but my data output looks like this:

```
Found SGX/MBX driver, enabling FullClearOnEveryFrame 
Found v1.4 driver, enabling brokenTexSubImage 
Found non-Nokia v1.4 driver, enabling brokenFBOReadBack 
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE  2048  SQRT  2 
Array Size:  16 
Data before roundtrip: 
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11 
12 
13 
14 
15 
Zero data: 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
Data after roundtrip: 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
Done...
```

How can I submit and read back my text properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You got a number of issues with this code. The main one being that ES 2.0 does not support float textures. Specifically:

- `GL_FLOAT` is not valid as the *type* argument of `glTexImage2D()` and `glTexSubImage2D()`. This needs to be `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, or one of various `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_*` options.
- The only *format*/*type* combination for `glReadPixels()` supported across all implementations is `GL_RGBA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. There is a second implementation dependent combination you can query.
- As others already pointed out, you're attempting to fill a texture with data, and then reading data from the current framebuffer. So even if both operations used valid arguments, you still would not get the data.

I would strongly recommend that you check some documentation before blindly trying to pass arguments that may or may not be valid to API calls. The [man pages](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/) are a good start. Also, use `glGetError()`, which will return error codes if you make invalid calls.

Implementations can support extensions that add support for some of the functionality you're looking for. E.g. [OES_texture_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) adds support for float textures. But you need to check for the presence of these extensions before attempting to use them.

Answer (score 3):

The code shown does not have a draw call that would use the texture and render to the default color buffer (a call like glDrawElements). The glReadPixels reads from the default Framebuffer. It can be changed in OpenGLES2 using *GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0*, not *GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT*

For the vast majority of TI devices with framebuffer support/nullws support, you can use the profiling code at below link. The below code tests some GPGPU scenarios including edge detection, colour conversion, and using FBO. Refer to calls to tests 11, 17

https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_gles20_vg.cpp

BTW, OMAP3 production chipsets have(had) SGX530 GPU not SGX540. SGX540/variants are used in the OMAP4 chipsets. You would be extremely lucky if you had a production OMAP3 variant with SGX540 :) You can confirm it in the bootlogs, or with the debug version of the PVR drivers.

Also mention what board/platform is being used.

Comment: Yes you are correct :) I the CPU is a DM3730 with the SGX530. Thanks for the link I will try this ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

> I then attempt to submit the texture to the GPU and read it back like this
>
> [...]
>
> So it is obvious that I am not "getting" the buffer back from OpenGL. I would expect it to contain the 1.5's, since I am reading the texture back with glReadPixels into my dataY array.

Why would it obviously not be the back buffer you are reading back?

You never render the texture to the color buffer, so reading back from the color buffer will never return the texture data.

The original code uses framebuffer objects to access the texture as a color buffer, which will have a totally different semantic in this scenario (it is still a mostly useless benchmark, though). Note that most real world ES2 devices also support the [`GL_OES_framebuffer_object` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_framebuffer_object.txt), so you can conceptually port that.

Comment: FBO support is standard in ES 2.0. No need for extensions.